# Is it better to use "<>" or "!=" for not equals in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I remember someone told me to use `<>` rather than `!=` but I forgot the reason why. I cannot find the answer on Google. Just want to know if they're just the same comparison operator or not because we're on refactoring stage of our MySQL codes now.

Comment: no difference i think see this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Answer (score 4):

`<>` is an ANSI SQL compatible operator, whereas `!=` is not.

So presumably you must use the former, since the latter is just a mysql's sql extension.

References:

- http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

> `<not equals operator> ::= <>`